# gRPC latency and throughput with large payload

Tags: java, performance, grpc, latency, grpc-java

I have a simple spring gRPC application with a dummy endpoint that does but returns an empty message:

proto:

```
message Map {
    map<string, string> value = 1;
}

service GreetingService {
    rpc GreetMap(Map) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}
```

implementation:

```
@Override
public void greetMap(Map request, StreamObserver<Empty> responseObserver) {
    responseObserver.onNext(Empty.getDefaultInstance());
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

I'm trying to load test this endpoint. I'm using a tool called [ghz](https://ghz.sh/).
I have generated a large proto message (327Kb) and I'm running this load tests on localhost (thus no network latency) for 200 requests with concurrency setting set to 20.

```
ghz --proto=service.proto -i path/to/imports/ --binary-file=output.bin --call=package.GreetingService/GreetMap --concurrency=20 --total=200 localhost:6565
```

And I'm the results is confusing:

```
Summary:
  Count:    200
  Total:    543.25 ms
  Slowest:  91.21 ms
  Fastest:  2.41 ms
  Average:  25.47 ms
  Requests/sec: 368.16

Response time histogram:
  2.412 [1] |∎
  11.292 [61]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  20.171 [32]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  29.051 [26]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  37.931 [39]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  46.810 [16]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  55.690 [12]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  64.570 [6]    |∎∎∎∎
  73.449 [2]    |∎
  82.329 [4]    |∎∎∎
  91.209 [1]    |∎

Latency distribution:
  10 % in 5.78 ms
  25 % in 9.93 ms
  50 % in 21.44 ms
  75 % in 36.80 ms
  90 % in 49.21 ms
  95 % in 61.35 ms
  99 % in 79.48 ms

Status code distribution:
  [OK]   200 responses
```

As we can see, the 95%% latency is more than 50ms and the throughput is 368.16 RPS.
If I run the same test with the small payload (6B) the result is completely different:

```
Summary:
  Count:    200
  Total:    30.96 ms
  Slowest:  14.86 ms
  Fastest:  0.35 ms
  Average:  2.90 ms
  Requests/sec: 6460.92

Response time histogram:
  0.354 [1] |
  1.805 [155]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  3.256 [4] |∎
  4.706 [20]    |∎∎∎∎∎
  6.157 [0] |
  7.608 [0] |
  9.059 [0] |
  10.509 [0]    |
  11.960 [0]    |
  13.411 [0]    |
  14.862 [20]   |∎∎∎∎∎

Latency distribution:
  10 % in 0.96 ms
  25 % in 1.25 ms
  50 % in 1.49 ms
  75 % in 1.70 ms
  90 % in 13.43 ms
  95 % in 14.51 ms
  99 % in 14.81 ms

Status code distribution:
  [OK]   200 responses
```

The throughput is about 20 times better (6460.92 RPS) and latency on 99%% is about 15ms.

The only thing that I [could find](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-go-perf-improvements/) is related to gRPC and payload size is about gRPC-Go and the latency with no network latency for the message of 1MB size described as within 5ms.

So is the handling on a big payload such an issue for gRPC or is it possible to fine-tune it for a better performance?

**UPD**
So I've tried to profile the application during the load tests and the results aren't very optimistic. Most of the CPU time is taken by message parsing. Of course, I'm not an expert in this, but it doesn't feel like something that can be optimized. Would be happy to be wrong
[image]

Comment: Did you warm up the Java server? Java's JIT takes 10-30 seconds of active work to compile enough of the application to provide meaningful benchmark numbers. As a baseline, a localhost 1k RPC with a noop service and one concurrent RPC takes ~154µs median and ~248µs at 99-percentile between a Java client and Java server, in gRPC's own testing which involves 60k RPCs after a warm-up.

Comment: @EricAnderson yeap, I did. So for this case, I can confirm that this is not a warm up issue, unfortunately for me

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but with Python. I'm comparing between REST and gRPC for 3 endpoints which return 100KB, 1MB and 4MB data with Concurrency (C) 1, 4, 10. For 100KB, gRPC win for sure, but for 1MB and 4MB, it's really slow for C 4 and 10. the throughput is 25% lower than REST, and average latency 35% slower than REST. I'm also trying to figure out this issue.

Comment: @Kaslie I did not compare it with REST. This might be a good idea. In case if you find anything, I would be very thankful if you share it with me :)

Comment: @Sergil Bishyr Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue with scalapb grpc client. Its slow on large response payload.

Comment: @Abhay I have decided to change the API so that the payload becomes smaller. It was the quickest and easiest way to go. Maybe it is possible to tune the deserialization a bit, but that wasn't the case for me